# Using Batch and Queueable causing Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2

Tags: apex, batch, callout, queueable-interface

I'm going to try and provide a blueprint of the code that I have in my production org.

**Batch**

```
global class EventBatchJob implements Database.Batchable<Event>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable {

    global List<Event> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // make a callout to get list of list of events from external web service
        return API.getEvents();
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Event> scope) {
        for(Event e : scope){
            RegistrantSyncQueueable esync = new RegistrantSyncQueueable();
            esync.event = e;
            esync.offset = 0;
            System.enqueueJob(esync);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }

    public static void run(){
        Type t = Type.forName('EventBatchJob');
        Database.Batchable< sObject > batchClass = ((Database.Batchable< sObject >) t.newInstance());
        Database.executeBatch(batchClass, 1);
    }
}
```

**Queueable**

```
public class RegistrantSyncQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private Integer lim = 1000;
    public Integer offset = 0;
    public Event event;

    public void execute(QueueableContext qc){
        // make a callout to get registrants (with limit and offset, paginated data) for event
        List<Registrant> registrants = event.getRegistrants(lim, offset);

        // logic to process and save data

        if(registrants.size() < lim){
            // reached last page
        } else {
            // enqueue another job for next page
            RegistrantSyncQueueable esync = new RegistrantSyncQueueable();
            esync.event = event;
            esync.offset = offset + lim;
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                System.enqueueJob(esync);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a batch size of 1 for my batch job and `Queueable` class has only one child `Queueable`. Now, this code randomly gives following error

> Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2

Is it possible that the batch job tries to queue `RegistrantSyncQueueable` and an existing running instance of `RegistrantSyncQueueable` tries to download next page and enqueues another instance of `RegistrantSyncQueueable` to cause this error?

I'm not much sure about the limits of using `Batch` and `Queueable` classes together. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Surely you don't get this error when you call `EventBatchJob.run()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can only execute or enqueue one job from a job, as noted in [Governor Limits on System.enqueueJob in Asynchronous Apex – Documentation Wrong?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/171611/2995)

As a simple alternative to your current approach, you can set the job size to `1`:

```
Database.execute(myBatch, 1);
```

I see you are already doing that in your `run` method, which can be simplified to:

```
Database.executeBatch(new EventBatchJob(), 1);
```

And in your script you can call:

```
EventBatchJob.run();
```