# Does Schedulable comes under sync scope or asycn scope?

Tags: apex, callout, future

I have a schedulable class and I am firing 50 future callouts from that. But as per documentation [click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm),it is mentioned that in synchronous context we can have 50 future callouts and for batch and future (Async context) its `0`.

How am I able to fire 50 future callouts from a scheduled job? Any explanation?

Small snippet used to test this :

```
public without sharing class TestFutureBatch implements Schedulable {
    public TestFutureBatch() {
        intPeriod = -1;
    }
    
    
    
    public void execute(SchedulableContext objContext) {
        // Query records with Limit 50
        // Verify id size is 50
        
        for (Integer i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            callFuture()
        }
    
    }
    
    @Future(Callout = true)
    callFuture(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally scheduled apex should obey the async limits, but this seems to be a known issue documented [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCG3QAM&title=scheduled-apex-don-t-respect-governor-limits-per-documentation) (with a work-around since few years).

*You might also refer to this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/does-scheduled-apex-use-synchronous-or-asynchronous-governor-limits). Schedulable apex seems to honor other sync limits as well (not just future calls).*

Only other documentation I could find from SF on this reference if given in the same link you provided in the question (see screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Schedulable Apex** is just like an anonymous apex code that you want to execute in a later period of time (*scheduled time*).

When the time arrives it will run the execute portion of the schedulable class as a **single synchronous transaction** and thus you are able to call the **50 @future callouts** as per the documentation.

Comment: So this means that if I wrap this logic in a batch and fire the same 50 future callouts from `finish` method of batch, will that still work?

Comment: @NagendraSingh No, batchable classes have async limits, including finish methods. Scheduleable is an exception to the async rules.

Comment: @sfdcfox If finish in Batchable class is async, we can still fire a future callout from `finish` right? Is this also an exception ?